# Running a Spring app on Glassfish 4.1.1 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException

Tags: java, spring, maven, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

Even though I prefer dealing with JavaEE applications, this e-commerce application (Shopizer) is a Spring app. I expected it to run smoothly on GF 4.1.1 but it keeps spitting errors that even Shopizer authors cannot precisely decipher. They rather expect their app to be a typical "write once, run everywhere" application.

This is the output I'm getting (make sure you scroll to the bottom as there's more info):

-- top to bottom output in the server's console --

```
.......
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '/sm-shop-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
Severe:   Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
Severe:   Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
Severe:   Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:773)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:353)

----  left out the middle part ----

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /sm-shop-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException
Info:   Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException. Please see server.log for more details.
```

The great `@BalusC` pointed out to me in a reply to my comment on some other (unrelated) question that the project may contain references to a `javaee` library somewhere. I told it to the authors and their reponse was:
***"Good point javaee.jar could have been pulled by a dependency but it is not the case. From your IDE you can see the pom dependency from sm-shop.
From what i saw glassfish looks for javaee xml file in the project and does not find it, maybe there is a way to skip that validation"***

So my question is: *How do I prevent GF to look for these stuff*

This is the link to Git (version 2.0.3) for anyone caring enought to take a look at the codebase: https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/tree/2.0.3

Thanks!

Comment: *"How do I prevent GF to look for these stuff"* You don't. As explaned before, your project's pom is just Tomcat minded and incompatible with Java EE. That part needs to be fixed. Tomcat is not a Java EE server. A Java EE server has already a lot of stuff builtin which you don't need to bundle into the webapp, such as an JAXP implementation (as indicated by the particular exception).